# Qué hago si no encuentro el Sql Server Configuration Manager en Windows 10 para SQL Server Management Studio v17.0 RC1?

Tags: sql-server

Tengo entendido de que en Windows 10 se busca de la siguiente manera `Control Panel→Administrative Tools→Computer Management`, pero cuando llego a `Computer Management` no me aparece el `Sql Server Configuration Manager`.

[image: esta imagen es un screenshot de donde se supone que aparezca]

Debe de aparecer debajo de Services and Applications, pero como pueden ver en la imagen no aparece.

Alguien sabe una solución para esto?

Answer (score 26):

El SQL Server configuration manager, generalmente es accesible como complemento de la consola de administración (*microsoft management console*: mmc.exe).

Puedes ejecutarlo directamente desde el cuadro de diálogo *ejecutar* (que a su vez puedes invocar con la combinación de teclas <kbd>Windows</kbd><kbd>r</kbd>.

En dicho diálogo, en el edit *Abrir* escribe:

- `SQLServerManager15.msc` para *SQL Server **2019***
- `SQLServerManager14.msc` para *SQL Server **2017***
- `SQLServerManager13.msc` para *SQL Server **2016***
- `SQLServerManager12.msc` para *SQL Server **2014***
- `SQLServerManager11.msc` para *SQL Server **2012***
- `SQLServerManager10.msc` para *SQL Server **2008***
- `svrnetcn.exe` para *SQL Server **2000***

Luego presiona <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Más información en la MSDN: [SQL Server Configuration Manager](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174212.aspx)

Comment: y sql server 2000? ;) jeje

Comment: @Pablo, si ves a alguien todavía utilizando SQL 2000, hay que quemarlo en la hoguera!!!. Y SQL 2000 en Windows 10, en serio???

Comment: Es arqueología. No creo que sigan usando el 2000 en ningun lado. Va...espero.

Comment: Jeje, entonces habrá que quemar a algunos... en sistemas antiguos (sea o no sea web) todavía te lo puedes encontrar :D

Comment: @Luis, no dudo que esté en uso, por eso no digo que no existan, sino que hay que acabar con ellos... jajaja. :D
Ahora, si existe, seguro estará también en XP, o quien saber, quizás hasta Windows 95 encuentres, pero en Windows 10... no me lo creo.

Comment: Me sirvió tu respuesta.
SQLServerManager14.msc para SQL Server 2017

Answer (score -4):

En Windows 10, opción buscar (o presionar la lupa) y allí escribir mmc o sino SQLServerManager14.msc (para SQL Server 2017), presionar enter y alli tienes tu SQL Server 2017 Configuration Manager.

También puedes presionar ctrl+r y luego escribir mmc o sino SQLServerManager14.msc

Saludos,